# Unable to update CentOS 7 - yum update broken

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm trying to run yum update and now it isn't working... I'm at a loss as to why - this is a fairly generic setup just running basic web, services:

```
[... tons of package updates...]

--> Running transaction check
---> Package libwayland-client.x86_64 0:1.14.0-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libwayland-server.x86_64 0:1.14.0-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package lz4.x86_64 0:1.7.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package systemd-libs.i686 0:219-57.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: liblz4.so.1 for package: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.5.2.el7 will be erased
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-693.11.1.el7 will be erased
---> Package systemd-libs.i686 0:219-57.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: liblz4.so.1 for package: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.i686 (base)
         Requires: liblz4.so.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Using `yum update --skip-broken` doesn't work.  And `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` does nothing.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?  I am not not able to update the server at all because it sticks at this point.

Comment: Have you tried to manually install that package? `yum install https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: I didn't try that, but I did run  yum install lz4 and it installed the library but still gives me the same error

Comment: Try running this next command: `yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts update`

Comment: running yum --setopt=tsflags=noscripts update gave me the same error:  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.i686 (base)
           Requires: liblz4.so.1

Comment: Note that you have a mix of both *x86_64* and *i686* packages installed. Usually, you just want one type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps I would take:

```
yum list installed | grep liblz4
```

If it's installed then:

```
sudo updatedb
locate liblz4.so.1
you should find a file called liblz4.so.1.7.5 or something like that.
copy that file to /usr/lib64
cd /usr/lib64
ln -s liblz4.so.1.7.5 liblz4.so.1
yum update
```

If it's not installed then install it like so:

`yum install https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Then repeat the steps above.

Just make sure that if your cpu arch is 64bit then you install the package for 64bit and then you place the file in `/usr/lib64` but if your cpu arch is 32bit then you should install the 32bit package and place the file in `/usr/lib` instead.

In addition, I'd try removing both liblz and systemd-libs and try to install the again and then run `yum update`.

**#Edit**

Following our chat, I advised you install the following package:

```
lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.i686.rpm
```

As I believe there was some mix up with your `liblz4.so.1` arch version and so far it seems like it solves your issue as the update process is running properly.

Comment: `yum list installed | grep liblz4` shows nothing, but `yum list installed | grep lz4` shows `lz4.x86_64 1.7.3-1.el7 @epel`

Comment: Remove this package and install the one in my answer and retry update please.

Comment: Before I do that.. check this out...

`yum list installed | grep -i systemd`
could this be the problem?
`systemd.x86_64                     219-42.el7_4.10                   @updates
systemd-libs.i686                  219-42.el7_4.10                   @updates
systemd-libs.x86_64                219-42.el7_4.10                   @updates
systemd-python.x86_64              219-42.el7_4.10                   @updates
systemd-sysv.x86_64                219-42.el7_4.10                   @updates`

I'm thinking the i686 shouldn't be there?

Comment: Yea exactly. Remove it and retry the update, waiting for your update.

Comment: By update you think the newer version of lz4 right?  not necessarily systemd-libs.  My research indicates it's not uncommon for there to be both x86_64 and i686 versions installed?

Comment: Here's what I'm worried about - this is an active production server.. do I risk any downtime doing these updates?  I don't know what systemd-libs does but it sounds pretty important.

Comment: If it's production then don't remove the systemd-libs package at all. Is this instance physical or in the cloud?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79206/discussion-between-itai-ganot-and-s-ov).

Comment: this is a cloud server... I did this sequence: `yum remove lz4` then `rpm -i lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` and installed a later version.  Still generated the same error on yum update

Comment: Let's move to chat please

Comment: Itai was right.. here's the SOLUTION:

Here's what ended up being the issue... Somehow, perhaps due to a temporarily glitch with one of the repositories, a 32-bit library file was substituted for a 64 bit or vice-versa.. and it failed.

finding the files in question

locate liblz4.so.1 

/usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1 
/usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1.7.5
I made a backup copy of them just in case, then ran this:

yum install https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/lz4-1.7.5-2.el7.i686.rpm
And that fixed the glitch.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue. I also noticed that I had two conflicting packages.

```
Error: Package: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.i686 (base)
       Requires: liblz4.so.1
```

So I looked a little further up the yum output and found that it was trying to upgrade from `---> Package systemd-libs.i686 0:219-42.el7_4.4` will be updated

So I did `yum remove systemd-libs.i686`

Finally fixed it for me.

Comment: Yup! This happened to us because something installed both the i686 & x86_64 versions of `systemd-libs.i686. Removing the i686 version fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using EPEL along with your CentOS 7 install.  Do you happen to be mirroring EPEL?  Does the lz4 package exist in your repo?

See https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/l/lz4-1.7.3-1.el7.x86_64.html

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm not sure what you mean.  It looks like maybe there's a different/higher version of lz4 that maybe I should install instead of what I just did?

Comment: this command shows:  rpm -qa | grep epel
epel-release-7-11.noarch

Is it possible that there's a newer version of lz4 library that I can manually install that might fix this?

Comment: Could this be the problem?    yum install lz4 put this version in: `lz4.x86_64              1.7.3-1.el7  @epel`

I can wget a newer version:

`wget https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS/Packages/l/lz4-1.7.3-1.el7.src.rpm`

Should I try to un-install the earlier version and install this one?

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this issue for several months now and finally got it solved.

I tried all the suggested solutions to no avail.

In my case the error was always:

```
Error: Package: systemd-libs-219-57.el7.i686 (base)
         Requires: liblz4.so.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest.
```

I finally noticed that during the attempts to update, a warning was issued during the first part of the procedure:

```
227 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
```

In my case, the solution to this issue was to edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf`:

Changed "enabled = 0" to "enabled = 1" and then ran `yum update`.

Then, all packages and dependencies have been installed properly.

Not sure if this will help anyone else - but it **solved the issue** for me.

Additional comment - I have tried this procedure on 2 servers that had the same issue - it worked both times.

I actually have 3 servers with identical CentOS 7 configuration.

The reason why only one of the three servers was able to complete updates installation with no issues is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, which was caused by a conflict arised from google-chrome package installed on my system. So, I removed google-chrome and the problem was removed.